# Vector Security manager - NEST

Tags: vector, nest

when i use Nest it give me
zenzefiNodeLayer missing pleass install correct version f secuirty manager and tryagain

when i read manual of nest it prefer to install vector security manger version 3.1.22.0 while i have 3.1.27.0

HOW CAN I SOLVE THIS ?